# Why PDF is larger in size in comparison to ePUB?

Tags: pdf, conversion, text-editors

I don't know a lot about both file formats but when I get a copy of books in each format, almost always PDF is larger than ePUB, with or without images.

for example, quick test shows that if I have plain txt document sized at 1mb, and convert it to either PDF or ePUB using online converter, the output is 400KB for epub and 1.8mb for pdf.
since it is plain text, it has no fonts, no size information, no metadata, no images, no tables etc.

what makes this difference?

Comment: "since it is plain text, it has no fonts". No - it has probably has fonts, embedded in the PDF to preserve fidelity. What program did you use for conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF, or *Page Description Format*, gives detailed information one *exactly* how the document should appear on any device. It supports advanced page layout features such as text boxes and image overlays, so text align precisely with an image. Even hard line breaks are specified. All this data takes up space.

EPUB, on the other hand, allows each device to reflow text and to display to best advantage *for that device*.

Each serves its purpose well. If I were publishing a document with many detailed illustrations, or one I didn't want altered, PDF would be my choice. For one to display on an ereader, EPUB would be my first choice -- note how MOBI and other protected files take up about twice the space, with no advantage to the user.

Comment: beautiful. or maybe I should use djvu, the compressed version of pdf? thanks for replying.

Comment: @medukia, it depends on your purpose. For example, few ereaders support djvu. If space is a priority, *some* publishing formats are fairly compressible in a zip archive. Also, when a PDF is created, it can use compression, or not.